# User and Friends relationship model in prisma ORM

Tags: node.js, orm, prisma

I have been struggling to create User and Friends relationship in Prisma and facing some ambiguous errors

So I have a User entity with the following Model

```
model Users {
  id       String  @id @unique
  name     String  
  email    String
  password String
}
```

Now I want to add a self-relationship with the many-to-many use case. where a user can have many Friends like following

```
model Users {
  id       String  @id @unique
  name     String  
  email    String
  password String
  friends Users[]
}
```

but Prisma is complaining me about this and i am unable to understand why cant we self reference here

Comment: What prisma version are you using ?

Comment: I am using 4.10.1

Comment: Did the answer bellow helped?

Comment: no that didnt worked .

Comment: What’s the error message?

Comment: I have answered my qs . reference https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/self-relations#many-to-many-self-relations

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to manage self relationship with n to n case would be as follow.

```
model Users {
  id       String @id @default(uuid())
  name     String
  email    String
  password String

  friends  Users[] @relation("friends")
  friendOf Users[] @relation("friends")
}
```

reference https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/self-relations#many-to-many-self-relations